# Doctrine annotation reader class not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I started to use doctrine in silex with simple annotations from docs `@Entity` and it worked. And now I see that symfony uses import `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` and `@ORM\Entity`. But when I add this, doctrine throws an error
`Class "App\Entity\Author" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Helpers\Jsonable;
use App\Helpers\MassAssignable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AuthorRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="authors")
 */
class Author
{
    use MassAssignable;
    use Jsonable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;
```

My config has no additional oprions

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([
    __DIR__.'/../src/Entity/'
]);


$app['db.em'] = EntityManager::create($app['db'], $config);
```

Comment: pls show the whole code :)

Comment: what is your doctrine config?

Comment: @Ludo, I use silex default provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `SimpleAnnotationReader` which cannot load annotations from not directly imported namespaces. You can switch this easily by passing `false` as 5th param for metadata config.

```
public static function createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array $paths, $isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null, $useSimpleAnnotationReader = true)
```

So in your case:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
    [__DIR__.'/../src/Entity/'],
    false,
    null,
    null,
    false
]);
```

Comment: ,strange but after I changed this setting, I still have the same error.

Comment: that's weird, is it possible that there is some problem with Silex namespace loading setup?

Comment: May be, I have composer with psr4 everything else works ok

Comment: well, one other thing you may try is to build the configuration manually, but for that would need to know exact setup, I'm not really familiar with Silex https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/advanced-configuration.html